# Is it possible to OrderBy a List after a certain element?

Tags: c#, linq, list, sql-order-by

As title says. I want to perform and order by on a list - but on a subsection of the list. To be precise, I want to order every element apart from the first.

EDIT: To clarify, I need to keep all (even the unsorted) elements once all of the sorting is done. (i.e. the first item (not sorted) to remain at the position it is at (at the start of the list) and all subsequent items sorted).

Comment: Note that the suggestions here are appropriate for a list.  However, had your Linq provider been Entity Framework or similar, you would need to check that the generated SQL is sensible.

Comment: Also, I think your edit, specifically, "at the end", is causing some confusion.

Comment: @Olly - haha I think so, apologies.

Comment: Isn't it wonderful having every word you type scrutinised by a zillion people and commented on extensively?!?  Such fun, such fun!

Comment: @Olly - haha I can't complain. It's understandable seeing as though attention to detail is crucial in discussions like this, I should've known better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
list.Take(1).Concat(list.Skip(1).OrderBy(predicate))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Although check right parenthesis. I think this may be the answer.

Comment: Dang, those are both great answers.

Comment: @Olly This is in the wrong order. The OP wants the beginning items at the end

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work if you want the beginning, unsorted items at the end:

```
list.Take(1).Concat(list.Skip(1).OrderBy(xyz));
```

Comment: that will lop off the first element, you will have to add the first one back in.

Comment: @DanielA.White I dont think the OP wants the first one, though...Could be a bad interpretation of the question...

Comment: You'll need to call `ToList` to get the `Add` method back.

Comment: Actually, I should be using Concat, typed too quick :)

Comment: I think the OP wanted the first element to remain first (always) then subsequent elements to be sorted.

Comment: @Olly `I need to keep all (even the unsorted) elements of the list at the end` gives me the impression that the skipped items should move to the end

Comment: Can't read his mind, but I think he means "in the end" rather than "at the end".  He can't literally want "all the elements at the end".

Comment: "I think the OP wanted the first element to remain first (always) then subsequent elements to be sorted" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
var results = list.Take(1)
                  .Concat(list.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x.Something))
                  .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Since posting the question has been edited to clarify that the unordered item(s) should be at "the end" of the collection, that can be achieved with a minor change of the above (just switching method calls around):

```
var results = list.Skip(1)
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Something)
                  .Concat(list.Take(1))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the initial items at the end

Comment: @BrokenGlass: some confusion here, but check OP's comment elsewhere to see that your original solution was the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing the first item then adding it back in (the method the other great answers have shown), you could get the index, and use it as part of the sorting:

```
list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .OrderBy(x => x.index != 0)
    .ThenBy(x => x.value)
    .Select(x => x.value)
    .ToList()
```